# is it possible to see the local declared variables in a function in "window" from the console?

Tags: javascript

I am sorry if this has been asked but I don't know if it's possible to see local variables of a function that is declared globally.

```
var a = function(a) {
var b = 2; // i need to see this in window
return a+b;
}
```

when i look at [[Scopes]]:Scopes[1] in window it only has Global index.

I need to know if this is possible and how to do it. Thank you

Comment: You might want to tell us _what you're trying to do_ instead.

Comment: I'm new in exploring console, i know it's easy to spot but I am curios if I can list them in logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, local variable are not global<sup>1</sup>, and cannot be accessed through `window`.

However, when you are [debugging the function call](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#scope), you can still access them in the console of your developer tools:

```
function a(a) {
    var b = 2;
    debugger;
    return a+b;
}
a(40);
```

<sub>1: that's the entire point</sub>

Comment: aha. so i have to invoke, never thought of that. thank you